# I am running a code that find tweets that are tweeted at somebody with '@' in the beginning and I am getting an error

Tags: python

when I run this I get an error message
typeError: sub() missing required argument 'string' (pos 2)

```
import re
import statistics
from statistics import mode

list = []
  for text in df['text']:
     username_re = re.compile(r'@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)')
     username = username_re.sub(text)
     list.append(username)

def most_repeated(list):
    return(mode(list))

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that you want to be using `re.sub`? `re.sub` will replace substrings in your text that match the pattern you supply and return the result. If you want to *extract* the username you should be using `re.match`. e.g.

```
username_re = re.compile(r'@(?P<username>[A-Za-z0-9_]+)')
username = username_re.match(text).group('username')
...
```

Secondly, the direct cause of the error: the `sub` method of a regular expression object (`username_re` in this case) requires at least two arguments:

1. `repl`: The string that will replace matching instances of your pattern.
2. `string`: The string that you will be replacing instances in.

For example, if you wish to *replace* the username in your string with the empty string, producing a string with no instances of your username pattern. You can do:

```
username_re = re.compile(r'@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)')
tweet_with_no_mentions = username_re.sub('', text)
```